# minecraft server error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've been getting this error for a very long time while trying to create a minecraft server with my friends. this is the error code:

```
06.02 20:50:53 [Server] main/INFO Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/WARN Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/WARN Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/WARN Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/WARN Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/WARN Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
06.02 20:50:54 [Server] main/INFO Reloading ResourceManager: Default
06.02 20:50:55 [Server] Worker-Main-8/INFO Loaded 7 recipes
06.02 20:50:55 [Server] Worker-Main-8/INFO Loaded 927 advancements
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Starting minecraft server version 1.16.5
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Loading properties
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Default game type: SURVIVAL
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Generating keypair
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Starting Minecraft server on <correct ip was here>:25667
06.02 20:50:56 [Server] Server thread/INFO Using default channel type
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/WARN **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/WARN The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/WARN Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/INFO Stopping server
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/INFO Saving worlds
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] Server thread/ERROR Exception stopping the server
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO java.lang.NullPointerException: null
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:572) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.t(SourceFile:599) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at zg.t(SourceFile:567) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:707) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:257) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
06.02 20:50:58 [Server] INFO at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212-1-ojdkbuild]
```

I would appreciate any help., thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is already running on port 25667. You can resolve this by changing your server port in server.properties to a free port or by stopping the process that is using current port (make sure it isn't something important before stopping it).

Here is how you can check what's running on it in case you want to do that:

(Windows)

```
netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr ":25667"
```

This command gives you the Process ID (PID). Then, you can open the task manager (ctrl + alt + del) and look in the processes tab to find the process with the matching PID. You can also use the tasklist command to get the name of the process:

```
tasklist | findstr <PID>
```

(Linux)

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ":25667"
```

On Linux, this command should give you both the PID and the process name.